# Resubmitting the revised version of an article after deadline

Tags: paper-submission, editors, deadlines, peer-review

I have already sent  a manuscript to an Emerald Journal. The manuscript was reviewed and the deadline for submitting the revised paper was set for July 30. It's been about a month since the deadline and now the paper is ready to resubmit. Is there usually an option to ask the editor to refer the article to the same previous referees ? If so, do I need to send a "response to reviewer" file when submitting an article?

Comment: Have you talked to the editor, perhaps asking for an extension?

Comment: @henning yes, but he did not response.

Comment: "Usually" doesn't help you here. Only the editor can help you.

Comment: Thanks @Buffy .

Comment: What's an emerald journal?

Comment: Did you communicate with the action editor at all when you missed the July 30 deadline?

Comment: @Azor Ahai -him-
Just two weeks before the deadline, I sent an email that went unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

- Yes, when you resubmit you usually submit also a response to reviewers, explaining how you addressed the points they raised (see [here](https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/research-publication/response-reviewers) for an example).
- Editorial processes are usually semi-automated.

So, if you did not receive any vaguely impersonal email reminder about the deadline for resubmission, it means that the editor most likely did not push the button "send reminder to authors", nor the button "say thanks to the authors but their time for resubmission is expired" and he is very ready to accept a resubmission.

Go through the webpage where you submitted the article, you should have the re-submission option (and instructions). If you cannot find it, phone call the editor.

Comment: Thank you, the reminder has been sent to me before I request the extension, however the submission option (for revised version) has been expired. I do not understand what you mean by the phrase "re-submission". 
Or maybe you do not understand what I mean.